# mapstruct: reuse mapper configuration is ignored

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to re-use an already defined Mapper on another one.

```java
@Mapper
public interface ReferenceUniqueIdentifierMapper {
        //...
    default String toPersistenceModel(ReferenceUniqueIdentifier id) {
        return id.getId().toString();
    }
}
```

In another Mapper, I'm trying to re-use previous defined mapper:

```java
@Mapper(uses = ReferenceUniqueIdentifierMapper.class)
public interface NestedReferenceMapper {

        //...

    @Mapping(source = "referenceUniqueIdentifier", target = ".")
    String toPersistenceModel(NestedReference persistence);
```

`Nestedrefference` is like:

```java
public class NestedReference {

    private final ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier;
        //...
}
```

So, I'm trying to map `NestedReference.referenceUniqueIdentifier` to String using `ReferenceUniqueIdentifier.toPersistenceModel(ReferenceUniqueIdentifier id)` .

Generated code is:

```
    @Override
    public String toPersistenceModel(NestedReference persistence) {
        if ( persistence == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String string = new String();

        return string;
    }
```

Any ideas about how to peak `ReferenceUniqueIdentifierMapper.toPersistenceModel` from `NestedReferenceMapper`?